# Map query result to typed list

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, lambda, resultset

Here is how I get the result(example):

```
OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from table_name t";     
//retrieve the result
OracleDataReader reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Then I have a POCO class that matches the fields of the query(row by row). That being said, I create a List:

```
List<ReportsModel> reports= new List<ReportsModel>();
```

Then I iterate over the `reader`:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
      //single report that I will pass to the colletion of reports
      ReportsModel report= new ReportsModel();
      report.Id_product = reader["ID_PRODUCT"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID_PRODUCT"]); 


      //passing report to reports
      reports.Add(report );
}
```

The problem is: my POCO class has around 300 fields(the query returns the same amount also). How can I map my result set (`OracleDataReader reader`) to my `List<ReportsModel>` without having to fetch row by row (`report.Id_product = reader["ID_PRODUCT"]`)? I know that there may be a way to solve it using something like lambda(arrow function) along with Linq or whatever.

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: HomeMadeSolution : Loop thru all the columns in reader, using reflection find property of `ReportsModel` which matches column name and assign value to it.

Comment: Or use Any ORM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the @mjwills suggestion on using Dapper and it solved my issue, here is my code:

```
string sql = "select * from table t ";   

//conn changed to IDbConnection, so I could use Dapper
var reports= conn.Query<ReportsModel>(sql).ToList();
```

And that's it, no need to write the code to iterate over OracleDataReader or anything else! Dapper handled it amazingly \o

**Useful:** [Dapper Example](http://dapper-tutorial.net/result-strongly-typed)